# Prove that $P(X_n>n\text{ i.o})=0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If we have a sequence of independent r.v.'s $X_i$ definied on the same space such that $E(X_i)=0$ and $E(X_i^2)=1$ for all $i\geq1$. Prove that $P(X_n>n\text{  i.o})=0$. I only know how to prove this if you know the probabilities and apply Borel Cantelli. How to approach this?

Comment: What mean : prove that $\mathbb P\{X_n>n\ \text{i.o.}\}$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry it should be ..=0 I changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By monotonicity of probability and Markov's inequality:

$P(X_n>n)\leq P(X_n^2>n^2)\leq P(X_n^2\geq n^2)\leq \frac{E[X_n^2]}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n^2}$

Comment: Why does the first inequality hold?

Comment: By monotonicity, because $\{X_n>n\}\subseteq\{X_n^2>n^2\}$. Formally, if at some point $\omega$ we have $X_n(\omega)>n$ then we square both sides (we can do that, both sides are positive) and get $X_n^2(\omega)>n^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction, but how do we know that $X_n(\omega)$ is positive?

Comment: We assume that $X_n(\omega)>n$, so it is positive.

Comment: But are the two sets then not equal? because $X_n>n$ is equivalent to $X_n^2>n^2$

Comment: Not necessary. If at a point $\omega$ we have $X_n(\omega)<-n$ then we also have $X_n^2(\omega)>n^2$ in that case. So the set $\{X_n^2>n^2\}$ might be bigger. However, there is the inclusion $\{X_n>n\}\subseteq\{X_n^2>n^2\}$.